# How to make monodevelop 5.6.2.5 on gentoo?

Tags: monodevelop, autotools, gentoo

./configure says "Now type `make' to compile MonoDevelop"

when i issue make command there is the following error occurs:

```
LANG=C mono ${S}/scripts/configure.exe gen-buildinfo ./build/bin
/usr/bin/git blame version.config
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

That's correct - it is not a git repository, because sources are unpacked from tarball (from github tag).

I don't understood:

1) how previous monodevelop-5.0.1.ebuild works through this

2) why i receive error "Unknown argument --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu" error when ebuild calls ./configure

Answer (score 1):

Tarballs should be created via `make dist`, not via the "extract as a tarball" function from github.

You have some already-generated tarballs of monodevelop [here](http://origin-download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/).